# A quicker way to parse a string that may have http urls in PHP?

Tags: php, string, parsing

I am trying to write a function to insert something to a string before and after URLs if any. For example, a string might be like this

```
"This is a string and some links, http://www.abc.com/xyz.html&p=123 and the other link is http://www.xyz.com/abc.html&x=2, that's all."
```

And I want to change it to (adding some html a tag before and after URLs)

```
"This is a string and some links, <a href="...">http://www.abc.com/xyz.html&p=123</a> and the other link is <a href="...">http://www.xyz.com/abc.html&x=2</a >, that's all."
```

I actually wrote a Lua function earlier to do something similar by using string.find() to find http and parse the string recursively.

I am relatively new to PHP and wondering if PHP has any function or technique that might perform this task easier?

Comment: You can use a `preg_replace` with a regular expression to match your http links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is ending characters.  For example, "I went to http://example.com/.  I found..." or "Have you visited http://example.com/?"

Now, if you can assume that there is always a space at the end of the URL and that it always starts with http://, then try this:

```
$url = preg_replace('/(https?:\/\/[^ ]+) /', '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $url);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's great to know this function can be done with just one function call, the fastest I could imagine. And I can understand the problem. In my previous Lua function, I used this, when http string starts, it only ends when a character not in following characters `, % @ ; = & ? $ - _ + ! * ' , : / . (all alphabets) (all digits)`.

Comment: $url = preg_replace('/(http:\/\/[^\,\%\@\;\=\&\?\$\-\_\+\!\*\\\'\,\:\/\.]+)/i', '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $url); -- I might have over-escaped things, but that's the idea.

Comment: what is the '/i' means? and should I remove '^'? how about all digits & all alphabets... sorry, I don't really understand regular expression. Hope you can help me. Thanks.

Comment: ok, I got it `preg_replace('/(http:\/\/[\%\@\;\=\&\?\$\-\_\+\!\*\'\:\/\.A-Za-z0-9]*)/', '<a href="$1">$1</a>'`

Comment: Glad you got it.  The /i means case-insensitive. (so the http:// could be written HTTP:// , too)

Comment: I know that this is old, but it should be `https?` instead of just `http`.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Yes, you are correct that it should be that for a more complete answer. I merely answered the question at the time.  I'll update.

Answer (score 1):

Well this is a start. But keep in mind that you can have some problem. I will say about that after the code.

```
$text = "This is a string and some links, http://www.abc.com/xyz.html&p=123 and the other link is http://www.xyz.com/abc.html&x=2";
preg_replace("/(http:)([^ ,]*)/", "<a href=\"$1$2\">$1$2</a>", $text);
```

That problem that you can run into is when you have some string right after a url like your example text: `This is a string and some links, http://www.abc.com/xyz.html&p=123 and the other link is http://www.xyz.com/abc.html&x=2, that's all.` there is a comma after a url, so you would have to put this into your regular expression as id did in my answer and changing a bit your text.

In my expression I'm considering that a URL starts with `http` and ends with anything that isn't a space character (or, in your particular case, a comma).

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's very surprised to me that it can be done with just one line of code, I am glad I asked this question here, that is great! I tried your code and it works. However, I am kind of stupid when it comes to regular expression. What if I want to test the string if it starts with "http" and as long as the subsequent characters are in these ones `, % @ ; = & ? $ - _ + ! * ' , : / . (all alphabets) (all digits)`  then it will be considered as part of the http string? Not using space as the end of http. Instead, use anything not in those characters above.

Comment: It says that the string must start with a `http` and end before everything else that isn't a space `([^ ,]*)` or a comma. The `^` inside the brackets denie a character after it (as I put a space and a comma it will denie theese two) the asterisk means that can be 0 or any quantity. I'm not so good at english hope I undestand what you have asked on your comment and answred right.

Comment: You did quite well, actually, Jorge.  I'm not sure why you used 2 groups for selecting and you forgot to assign teh results of the preg_replace. ;)

Comment: @JeremyMiller Yes you are right about the two groups just one would do the catch and I didn't assign because the OP just ask if it was possible, so my intention was to show how to do it and then he can learn by himself :)